# JPA metamodel generation in maven multi-module project with both annotations and xml

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, metamodel

I have a maven multi-module project. This project has several modules each of which have some entities inside. Some of them are JPA-annotated, some of them are simple POJOs without any annotations. There is one project dependent on all those modules. This project contains xml orm mappings for all entities that were not annotated with JPA.

I'd like to generate a JPA metamodel on project build (or, to the best, automatically when source code files change).

Currently I'm using this approach [JPA Hibernate Metamodel generation through maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528290/jpa-hibernate-metamodel-generation-through-maven) but modified a little. The thing is my configuration has both xml-based and jpa-based mappings and this wouldn't work; when I run it as it is the metamodel is generated only from jpa-annotated entities contained inside this main project.

I have managed to generate metamodel for all xml mapped classes by specifying them explicitly in configuration of maven-processor-plugin. This isn't pretty though. What I cannot manage is to generate the metamodel for jpa-annotated classes outside the main module but in the classpath. For some reason they are not picked up automatically despite being on the classpath.

I would like to generate a metamodel for all XML-based and Annotation-based mappings present on a classpath.

The other strange thing is that when I clean install on the main project it works (partly - meaning that XML mapped metamodel is generated) but when I do the same thing at the root project, containing all other projects it doesn't do it.

I run out of options. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have also read

Comment: Can't you migrate to one approach ? possibly to annotation.

Comment: How it would help? As I mentioned jpa-annotated entities belonging to other modules are not recognized.