# Generated metamodel via hibernate tools but i cannot use it

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

previously i had problem with duplicate

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile     (default-compile) on project WebAppTest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\Luppo\workWS\WebAppTest\target\generated-   sources\annotations\com\pl\war\ldap\config\model\AbstractEntity_.java:[9,16] error: duplicate class: c  om.pl.war.ldap.config.model.AbstractEntity_
```

I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528290/jpa-hibernate-metamodel-generation-through-maven)

after `mvn compile` command  metamodel classes was been generated, but I can't use it

I need find user by login

```
public List<User> findByLogin(String login) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
    Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
    criteriaQuery.select(root).distinct(true);
    if (login != null) {
        predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                builder.equal(root.get("login"), login));
    }
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
}
```

when I'm searching with "login" everythiong is ok but if I want use `User_.login`. No import, no tip, eclipse sees no class. Metamodel location is

```
Project
 |_target
   |_generated-sources
     |_apt
      |_(and whole corectly package e.g com.pl.xxx)
```

Somebody knows why I can't use metamodel classes ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I have to add

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <!--version>1.2.0.Final</version -->
                    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Now metamodel is generating but always I can't use in eclips, but if I add my directory

```
Properties -> Java build Path -> Link Source (target-> generate-sources)
```

Everything works